# Lagrange Polynomial not plotting in Octave

Tags: octave

The question requires a Lagrange polynomial L(c) to replace the complicated-looking function, f. Also, plot function f and L(c) between [1:0; 10:0]. However, after the code computes the values for k, it cannot seem to create a plot and a graph. What am I doing wrong? Attached is the code below. Thank You!

````
clear
pkg load symbolic
graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')
syms m x
c = []
for i = 1: 0.5 : 10
  c = [c,i]
endfor
d = length(c)
k = []
f = 3.* (1 .- ( 8 ./ vpa(pi.^2) .* ((1 ./ cosh(vpa(pi) .* vpa(x) ./ 2)) .+ symsum(1 ./ ((2 .* m .+ 1).^2 .* cosh((2 .* m .+ 1) .* vpa(pi) .* vpa(x) ./ 2)), m,1 ,Inf)))) ./ ((1 .- ( 192 ./ vpa(x) .* vpa(pi.^5)).*(tanh(vpa(pi) .* vpa(x) ./ 2) .+ symsum(tanh((2 .* m .+ 1) .* vpa(pi) .* vpa(x) ./ 2) ./ (2 .* m .+ 1).^5, m,1 ,Inf))));
for i = 1:d
  A = (1 - ( 192 / vpa(c(i)) * vpa(pi^5))*(tanh(vpa(pi) * vpa(c(i)) / 2) + symsum(tanh((2 * m + 1) * vpa(pi) * vpa(c(i)) / 2) / (2 * m + 1)^5, m, 1, Inf)))
  B = 1 - ( 8 / vpa(pi^2) * ((1 / cosh(vpa(pi) * vpa(c(i)) / 2)) + symsum(1 / ((2 * m + 1)^2 * cosh((2 * m + 1) * vpa(pi) * vpa(c(i)) / 2)), m, 1, Inf))) 
  K = 3 * B / A
  k = [k,K]
endfor
col = c(1)
matrixc = [];
for m = 1:d;
  prod = 1;    
  for t = 1:d
    if col == ((m+1)/2)
      col = col .+ ((10-1)/(d-1));
    endif   
    sol = (x.-vpa(col))./(vpa((m+1)/2).-vpa(col));
    prod = prod*sol;   
    col = col .+ ((c(2)-c(1))/(d-1));  
  endfor
  h = k(m);
  p = vpa(h).*prod;
  matrixc = [matrixc,p];
  col = 1;
endfor
L=sum(matrixc);
L
ezplot(L,[c(1),c(d)]);
hold on;
k(1)
plot(c,k);
legend('Lagrange Polynomial','K(x)');
xlabel('x-axis');
ylabel('y-axis');```
````

Comment: Don't tag spam. If you write in Octave, why the bother with unrelated tags as Python and MATLAB?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? E.g. unknown terminal type? while plotting with gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot a symbolic variable.
I don't know if this is possible in general, but in this particular case at least the conversion is causing problems

Collect the values of the symbolic variable first, by casting to `double`, and then you can plot as intended:

```
plot( c, double(k) );
```